# cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: android

please help when i run my application i get these errors, im trying to make an android game

i have been trying to solve this problem and other problems for more than 3 days

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zargoun.please"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zargoun.please.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

StackTrace

```
     D/AndroidRuntime(1115): Shutting down VM
     W/dalvikvm(1115): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.zargoun.please/com.zargoun.please.Main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zargoun.please.Main cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zargoun.please.Main cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
     E/AndroidRuntime(1115):    ... 11 more
```

i get Error: The method setContentView(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Maing)

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private Maing _game;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _game = new Maing();

        setContentView(_game);
    }


}
```

this is the class maing.java it implements Screen from libgdx library

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public class Maing implements Screen{

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zargoun.please.Main cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`  Please post the class declaration for `Main`

Comment: Does com.zargoun.please.Main extends Activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your "Main" class doesn't extend Activity. That's all I can see with only your manifest and StackTrace.

Comment: yes, but i need to extend class game any idea how ??
im not good in java

Comment: A game in Android can be created in two ways: Using a SurfaceView (Which will practically be your game's screen and uses bitmaps or drawables to draw) or using OpenGL ES1.0 or 2.0. OpenGL is more advanced, but is more suited to big projects, and most people download pre-made engines to use it. setContentView takes as an argument either a View (like the SurfaceView I was talking about before) or a layout resource ID (like R.layout.your_layout). To create a game you need to read about SurfaceView or download a game engine such as AndEngine.

Comment: i used AndEngine and i already success, but AndEngine's Box2d is very stupid or im the stupid. so i decided to use libgdx which has a good Box2d that what i want to do, but i failed to interface it with android Acticity

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Main class is not extending Activity, but please post it.

You should have:

`public class Main extends Activity { }`

---

**EDIT**

You should learn a bit more about java and android.
Basically you are creating a Maing object (I don't have an idea on what it could be) and passing it to the setContentView method. The problem is that this doesn't make any sense. The setContentView method accept only an int parameter, pointing to the xml layout file.

In Android you have to define your layout in an xml file and then pass it to the Activity into the setContentView. If you try to tell us about the library that you're using or what you're trying to do we can be more helpful.

---

**EDIT2**

That's why I asked you about the library. If you're using libGDX I don't have any idea on why you're setting a view. You don't have to because everything will be managed in your main game project, not in the Android one. In your Activity you have just to extends the AndroidApplication and start the game.

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        // your configuration        
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

I suggest you to READ THE DOCUMENTATION and go through a simple tutorial like the [many on the libgdx site](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) (like [this one](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/)).

Comment: i tried this but doesnt work too

public class Main extends Activity {
 
 private Maing _game;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  _game = new Maing();
  
  setContentView(_game);
 }

 
}

The method setContentView(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (Maing)

Comment: i already knew the problem, the class im pointing to is not extending a view class. do you have any suggestion how can i fix it

Comment: Edited. I guess you should learn a bit more about the Android basics, or tell us about the library you're using to make the game. :;)

Comment: i already added the maing class above, im using libgdx library 
i already success to make the game using that libgdx setup, but that application listener limits my android activity while i need to use it fully. and honestly i couldn't interface it with the libgdx android project at all
( sorry for late reply due to the time difference )

Comment: Edited. Please have a look and let me know. Please, feel free to accept my answer if you find it useful. : )

Comment: i know this and i already made a game which using box2d, in that box2d i have 2D arm which have 3 revolute joints. 
what i want to do is controlling the box2d arm so the real robot arm move. to do this i have to extend ioioactivity. it same as Android Activity. if i made a new class which which extends ioioactivity it won't work because the libgdx-android takes from the core only